# Android Studio: Editing a .txt file in internal storage with EditText

Tags: java, android, file

I have a .txt file in the internal storage (the app's data directory)
and I have an EditText field that loads up the content in the .txt file.

I want to apply the changes the user makes to that EditText field, and I'm not sure what to do. I tried OutputStreamWriter, but the changes didn't apply.

Any help/guidance is appreciated

This is the code for onClick on the save button:

```
File file = ....;
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
String res = editText.getText().toString();
OutputStreamWriter out= new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
out.write(res);
out.close();
```

the reason I use file.getName() in the openFileOutput parameter is because i got the error with path seperators

Comment: do you close your stream at the end of your code?

Comment: yea i closed the stream at the end

Comment: please show some lines of code

Comment: it's included now in the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this code:

```
File file = ....
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
String res = editText.getText().toString();        
myOutWriter.write(res);
myOutWriter.close();
fOut.close();
```